# Camel route responding to web application synchronously

Tags: apache-camel, embedded-resource, synchronous

I understand you can embed Camel in  web application or stand alone application by creating a Camel context. This means that routes could be started from within your application. Great!

How can I go the other way and get my route to return a response to the application, thus creating a response/request and therefore synchronous interaction?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a [ProducerTemplate](http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html).

What you need to do is to get hold of the camel context and create one ([that you should reuse](http://camel.apache.org/why-does-camel-use-too-many-threads-with-producertemplate.html)).

```
ProducerTemplate pt = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
... 
String text = pt.requestBody("direct:someroute", "Hello World", String.class);
```

Comment: Thanks Petter. I sort of get this. How is the response handled though? I need a response for the interaction to be synchronous.

Comment: Specifically - how does the blueprint.xml send back, or does the ProducerTemplate class just need to catch it somehow? I am really confused.

Comment: Okay, I updated the answer with the producerTemplate to receive a response as well. A camel route replies to the "from" URI (if an applicable protocol) with whatever is in the Exchange at the end of the route given that the exchange pattern is InOut. `pt.requestBody` sets the ExchangePattern to InOut. Read more about this here: http://camel.apache.org/request-reply.html